# Can JTable be resized by the user dragging the mouse

Tags: java, swing, printing, jtable, jscrollpane

So I am creating a GUI and it has a JTable that is set inside of a JScrollpane. When the user opens the window it displays everything how I want it to. The user can add rows to the table to fill in data and then they can scroll through the information. I also have a JButton which I have set to print the whole window. Now my problem is the table prints but only shows the data in the viewing area. What i was thinking was if the user could drag the bottom corner of the JTable to re size it to show everything then everything would be ok, I'm just not sure if that's even possible or how to do it. Ive been searching and i haven't seem to come across anything like this yet.

**Edit:**
So for anyone else here is the link to the class I found. It allows you to use the mouse to resize any component.

http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/09/13/resizing-components/

Comment: Just resize the frame and the viewport of the scrollpane should also increase in size when you use an appropriate layout manager.

Comment: Ok so i figured it out. It wont let me post the answer yet since i have to low of a reputation. I will post the answer in 8 hours when it will finally let me.

Comment: Thanks for the help I got it working how I wanted it too :)

Comment: Take a snapshot of the table, not the window

Answer (score 2):

To get an image of the entire table you can try using [Screen Image](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/13/screen-image/), which allows you to take an image of a specific component.